# Flextables adhere when rendering in a for loop

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable, officedown

I'm struggling with flextables adhering to each other when I render them in a for loop in my rmarkdown notebook. The output is docx (officedown::rdocx_document to be precise). This is my code:

```
dt <- head(iris)
for (i in 1:10) {
  flextable_to_rmd(flextable(dt))
}
```

The result is a set of flextables but without any space between them and it causes problems when a table spans over two pages. It get unreadable for more complex tables.

The only workaround I found is adding `cat("--")` as the las line inside the for loop. Is there more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Use argument `text_after` and add '--' between tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code let you add an empty Word paragraph after each table.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r results='asis'}
library(flextable)
dt <- head(iris)
for (i in 1:10) {
  flextable_to_rmd(flextable(dt), text_after = "<w:p/>")
}
```
````

[image]